# Debugging Django Forms validation errors

Tags: python, django, django-forms

One of my forms fails on form.is_valid()

First time I am debugging a Django form. So, I am not sure where to look for the validation error

forms.py

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self,user,*args,**kwargs):
    super(ImageForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs) # populates the form

class Meta:
    model = KMSImageP
    fields = ('name',
              'caption',
              'image',
              )
```

models.py

```
from photologue.models import ImageModel

class KMSImageP(ImageModel):

name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
slug = AutoSlugField(max_length=45, unique=True, populate_from='name')
num_views = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False, default=0)
caption = models.TextField(_('caption'), blank
```

I got that

```
>>>> image_form.__dict__['_errors']
>>>>django.forms.util.ErrorDict({'image': django.forms.util.ErrorList([<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0xecc770>])})
```

So I am guessing that my 'image' field (an ImageField inherited from an abstract base class) is the cause of the failure but I don't know why.

I've tried changing the type of the attributes to FileField (as my other forms use FileField to upload with no problem) but it still fails... Anyhow, I am clueless...

Comment: can post the form-class definition.  Its tough to figure it out from just this.

Comment: and post the result of `print form.errors['image']`

Comment: print form.errors['image']

<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul>

... Obviously I do select a file before submit and the name is displayed next to the field...

Comment: updated the question with forms and class definitions

Comment: anyone ?

just got back on this and haven't solved it yet.

Answer (score 5):

You really should learn how to use debugger with Django and it's built in server- it has saved me lot's of print/dir expressions and endless edit-run-observe output-edit iterations.

The most basic way to debug python applications is by using [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html)
It's as easy as dropping in these two lines of code:

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

in that part of code you want to debug. As soon as the second line is executed, program execution stops at that point and you have to switch to console and you can observe the state and contents of variables, execute next line, go to next breakpoint and so on. Just type ? and press enter.
Of course, if you use sophisticated enough IDE debugging is much more easier than this, but this should get you a general idea of how to use debugger.

Comment: haven't used pdb yet as I am using werkzeug http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/download
great tool

thanks for the tip

I'll